# Copy data to new column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, automation, google-apps-script-triggers

I have a sheet with `IMPORTHTML` that I want to copy data from one column to a new column daily.

```
function saveData() {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Daily ledger'), true);
      spreadsheet.getRange('x3:x96').activate();
      spreadsheet.getRange('N3:N96').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```

This script works well, but I have to change `x3:x96` every day (tomorrow I would have to change it manually to `y3:y96` etc.), I also have to change the trigger date daily.

Is there a way to do it automatically? To have a script paste in a new column every day?

[I know there is a way to do it in new row](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/saving-data-in-google-sheets/), but that is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
spreadsheet.getRange(3, spreadsheet.getLastColumn()+1, 93, 1).activate();
```

This will activate the next right most column range from row 3 to 96.

This can also be accomplished in a more easy and in an understandable way by doing something along the lines of,

```
function saveData() {
    const ledger = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Daily ledger');
    ledger.getRange(3, ledger.getLastColumn()+1, 93, 1).setValues(ledger.getRange('N3:N96').getValues());
}
```